# How to lock phone orientation in Android to prevent landscape mode

Tags: android

Is this possible to do? Landscape mode distorts the background image, and therefore I would like to lock orientation to vertical on phones with accelerometers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can force the screen orientation to always be portrait for individual activities in the [manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen).  You use the

```
android:screenOrientation
```

attribute with the value "portrait" in each of the activities you want to always have the portrait orientation.

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
...
</activity>
```

Answer (score 6):

May be a duplicate question, but yes, here's one way to do it:

```
// This forces a vertical screen.
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Comment: Need to import this library: android.content.pm.ActivityInfo